# Modifying array right before instantiating a fragment with a gridview in tablayout is not applying, why?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have a simple app with multiple tabs, each tab has its own fragment with a gridview. I use the same gridview adapter for each fragment. I have a static string array that changes based on the tab selected. However, for whatever reason I am getting a strange behavior where the the grid cycles back to the front repeating itself until the length of the array is met. The array is `names`and I modify it within the switch statement of the MainActivity. Here is a couple pictures of the strange behavior, as you can see:
[Gridview top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hgKX.png)
[Gridview bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI62O.png)

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static MainActivity instance;

    private FragmentOne fragmentOne;
    private Fragment2 fragment2;
    private Fragment3 fragment3;

    private TabLayout allTabs;
    public static String[] names;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        instance=this;

        getAllWidgets();
        bindWidgetsWithAnEvent();
        setupTabLayout();
    }

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private void getAllWidgets() {
        allTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    }

    private void setupTabLayout() {
        fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
        fragment2 = new Fragment2();
        fragment3 = new Fragment3();

        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.iconfav),true);
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("Mexico"),true);
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("Names"));
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("Replies"));
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("Money"));
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("Political"));
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("Success"));
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("Other"));

    }

    private void bindWidgetsWithAnEvent()
    {
        allTabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                setCurrentTabFragment(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void setCurrentTabFragment(int tabPosition)
    {
        switch(tabPosition){
            case 0:
                replaceFragment(fragmentOne);
                break;
            case 1:
                MainActivity.names = new String[]{"Not Sending Best", "Mexico", "Can't beat", "Beat Mexico", "Pay for",
                        "Immigration", "Government", "Ford is moving"};
                replaceFragment(fragmentOne);

                break;
            case 2:
                MainActivity.names = new String[]{"The Best Man", "President Trump", "Bernie Sanders", "Tiffany", "Mexico",
                        "Saudi Arabia", "Ivanka", "Kay Donnie Don", "Friends Germany"};
                replaceFragment(fragment2);

                break;
            case 3:
                MainActivity.names = new String[]{"Thank You", "Thank You 2", "I'm Sorry", "No" , "Doesn't Exist",
                        "I Don't Know", "Don't Worry", "Wrong","That's Right", "What I Say", "Tell You This",
                        "Makes Sense", "Have to Get Going", "Fully Understand","Did You Ask", "Get Him Out"};
                replaceFragment(fragment3);

                break;
            case 4:
                replaceFragment(fragmentOne);
                break;
            case 5:
                replaceFragment(fragmentOne);
                break;
            case 6:
                replaceFragment(fragmentOne);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


    }

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

And my GridViewAdapter:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;


    public GridViewAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {


            return MainActivity.names.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            /*imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);*/

            textView = new TextView(mContext);
            textView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView.setText(MainActivity.names[position]);
            textView.setTextSize(18);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            //imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            textView = (TextView) convertView;
        }

        //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);



        //return imageView;
        return textView;
    }

}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
}
```

Fragment3:

```
private GridView gridView;
    public static int SIZE = 8;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, null);
        getAllWidgets(rootView);
        setAdapter();

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                PlayAudio(position);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private void getAllWidgets(View view) {
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridViewFragmentOne);
    }

    private void setAdapter()
    {

        GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(MainActivity.getInstance());
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
    }

    public void PlayAudio(int position) {

        // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.thank_you_darling);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case 1:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.thankyouverymuch);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case 2:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.r_im_sorry);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case 3:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.r_no);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case 4:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.r_does_not_exist);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case 5:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.r_dont_know_whats_happening);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case 6:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.r_dont_worry);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case 7:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.wrong);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case 8:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.r_thats_right);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case 9:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.r_what_i_say_is_what_i_say);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case 10:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.r_tell_you_this);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case 11:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.r_makes_sense);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case 12:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.r_have_to_get_going);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case 13:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.r_fully_understand);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case 14:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.r_does_not_exist);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case 15:
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.gethimout);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


    }
```

Comment: can you add your fragment code please

Comment: ok added fragment3, the fragment where its happening

Answer (score 0):

try overriding this method on fragment and set adapter in this method:

```
    @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
   if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {
       setAdapter();
   }
}
```